# How long does iOS app take to display in AppStore/iTunes?

Tags: ios

My developer has submitted my Application to the Appstore today, but how long does it take to actually see the new app in the Appstore? Note that it is an update to the existing app...(so not really a new app, went through all the processes, it is already approved and everything just waiting for app to appear in store)

Thanks

Comment: If he has submitted the app today then it is not approved. For updates it takes less time, but still about 4 or 5 days in best scenarios. Look for other posts, this has been treated many times!

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did look for similar questions but most of them are about the process to submitting the app. I have already submitted the app...

Comment: http://reviewtimes.shinydevelopment.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App updates too take the same amount of time for review as it takes for a new app submission. It can take anywhere from 5 days to a couple of weeks. Once approved, it will appear in the app store within a day's time.

Comment: thank you, appreciate your answer. I did not know that and it is not exactly on the main page of apple.com...

Comment: You can find the information here: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/index.html#expect

The average time taken for review keeps varying based on the number of requests that Apple is processing. There is a live App Store Review Status in that page.